# User selection in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

User selection in Javascript?
So I have a folder, and in the folder I have 2 other folder one is about.html and the other is main.html........ So my question is if I m on my main html page and have my about in `<ul><li>about<li><ul>` And I want if I click on the about, I want it to go to the about.main html...... So basically I want to know how can I can about.html to my main.html so went I click it, it take me straight to my about page...... Hope somebody can help I m new to JavaScript so take it easy on me

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to make the `index.html` of the folder `about.html` into `main.html`?

Comment: i want, so if i click the "about" link on my main index.html page, so it can take me to the "about" page. @k97513

Comment: So when you click say `about`, it brings you from `/index.html` to `/about/main.html`?

Comment: @k97513 nope it dont, but that was my question...how do i make it to do that?????

Comment: So you mean when you go to `/about.html/main.html`, you want it to redirect to `/index.html`?

Comment: @k97513 yes when i click the about on the main.html i want it to redirect me the about page.

Comment: document.location.assign('projects/' + opsArray[i].value + '/');
    or is it something like this?

Comment: Add an `<a href="/projects/about.html">About</a>` if you want to go to `/projects/about.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying why not just use an a tag eg.

```
<a href="folder1/about.html">About</a>
<a href="folder2/main.html">Main</a>
```

You can do this in javascript like this

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href="folder1/about.html";
link.click();
```

Comment: Doesn't he have a folder named `about.html`?

Comment: these look correct, thanks will try them, and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: I don't know I'm fairly confused I think it is a HTML file